# Can't access game objects "reference to non-static member function must be called"

Tags: c++, static-methods

I'm making a snake game and I'm trying to refactor my main function into a call to a Game object (Game.run() or something like that). I will post all of the code below, but the basic set up is that I have a Snake object, a Window (which does rendering for me), a Food object and a couple of Timers. In the current main function I instantiate all of these at the start and then use them later on. I want to refactor all of this into a Game class which has the Snake, Window, Food and Timers as instance variables. The issue I'm having is that I can't access these members later on! The error I get is "C++ "reference to non-static member function must be called".

Here is a bit of the original code:

```
int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {
  Window window("Snake", GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT, GRID_STRIDE);
  Snake snake(window, GRID_STRIDE, 20, 20, 255, 255, 255, 255);
  Food food(window, GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT, GRID_STRIDE, 192, 192, 192, 255, time(0));
  Timer fpsTimer;
  Timer capTimer;

  int countedFrames = 0;
  fpsTimer.start();
  bool updateDisplay = true;
  while (!window.isClosed()) {
    capTimer.start();
    pollEvents(window, snake);
    if (updateDisplay && !snake.isDead()) {
      window.draw();
      snake.draw();
      food.draw();
      checkCollisions(snake, food);
      snake.checkSelfEat();
    }
}
```

This works fine. But when I refactor it into a game class:

```
//game.h

class Game {
  public:
    Game(int g_width, int g_height, int g_stride, int fps);
    virtual ~Game() {};
    void run();

  private:
    int grid_width, grid_height, grid_stride, screen_fps, screen_ticks_per_frame;
    Window window(std::string title, int g_width, int g_height, int g_stride);
    Snake snake(Window &window, int g_stride, int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, int a);
    Food food(Window &window, int g_width, int g_height, int g_stride, int r, int g, int b, int a, int random_seed);
    Timer fpsTimer, capTimer;
};
```

with implementation:

```
// game.cpp

Game::Game(int g_width, int g_height, int g_stride, int fps) :
grid_width(g_width), grid_height(g_height), grid_stride(g_stride), screen_fps(fps) {
  Window window("Snake", grid_width, grid_height, grid_stride);
  Snake snake(window, grid_stride, 20, 20, 255, 255, 255, 255);
  Food food(window, grid_width, grid_height, grid_stride, 192, 192, 192, 255, time(0));
  Timer fpsTimer;
  Timer capTimer;
  screen_ticks_per_frame = 1000 / screen_fps;
}

void Game::run() {
  int countedFrames = 0;
    fpsTimer.start();
    bool updateDisplay = true;
    while (!window.isClosed()) {
      capTimer.start();
      pollEvents(window, snake);
      if (updateDisplay && !snake.isDead()) {
        window.draw();
        snake.draw();
        food.draw();
        checkCollisions(snake, food);
        snake.checkSelfEat();
      }
};
```

I would really like to understand this, I got the same error when I tried to use GoogleTest test fixtures too. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great!

For instance, one error is:

error: reference to non-static member function must be called
    while (!window.isClosed()) {

With the window underlined. EVERY instance of window, snake, food, timer is errorring, with the instance underlined.

Some help on this would really be appreciated, sorry if I haven't been clear enough in this post.

Comment: `Window window(std::string title, int g_width, int g_height, int g_stride);` declares a function that returns a `Window` - it does not initialize a variable of type `Window`

Comment: And in your constructor you create *local* objects, which no longer exist after the constructor is finished

Comment: This seems so fundamental, thank you! Would you be able to comment/answer what I should be writing?

Comment: I see! C++ is hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two fundamental issues in your code. The first is that you are declaring `private` functions, not member variables. To declare member variables you only need to use the type and variable name, e.g.:

```
class Game {
  // public omitted for brevity
  private:
    int grid_width, grid_height, grid_stride, screen_fps, screen_ticks_per_frame;
    Window window;
    Snake snake;
    Food food;
    Timer fpsTimer, capTimer;
};
```

The second issue is that in your constructor body you declare *local* variables with the same name as the "members" - these are not the same though and the local ones get destroyed after the constructor is finished.
You should use the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), as you already do for the `int` members, e.g.:

```
Game::Game(int g_width, int g_height, int g_stride, int fps) :
grid_width(g_width), grid_height(g_height), grid_stride(g_stride), 
screen_fps(fps), window("Snake", grid_width, grid_height, grid_stride), 
snake(window, grid_stride, 20, 20, 255, 255, 255, 255), 
food(window, grid_width, grid_height, grid_stride, 192, 192, 192, 255, time(0)),
screen_ticks_per_frame(1000 / screen_fps){
  // no need to repeat the Timers
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this to me!